# Unicode into iterable list

Tags: python, json

I'm having trouble using a list that is represented in unicode. I've tried looking at other questions and the json.dumps() function shows a u'string' but it isn't the case for me. I can't iterate over the list because python sees the whole thing as a string and gives me individual chars. Here is some code.

```
print flist
print type(flist)

['a', 'b', 'c']
<type 'unicode'>

myjson = json.dumps(flist)
print myjson
print type(myjson)

"['a', 'b', 'c']"
<type 'str'>
```

Shouldn't it be? :

```
[u'a', u'b', u'c']
```

Comment: What about `json.loads()` instead of `json.dumps()`?

Comment: How did you define `flist`?

Comment: json.loads() turns it back into <type 'unicode'> like flist. flist is from an object I manually typed  ['a', 'b', 'c'] into the django database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ast.literal_eval

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(flist.decode())
```

Comment: ['a', 'b', 'c']
<type 'str'> ... nope

Comment: Try without the json.dumps , you may need to use .decode() on the string as well before giving to ast.literal_eval()